# RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirect-loop

I am writing 301 redirect first time...

### Objective

I have to redirect any URL

- `www.example.com/product/cat/item/product-item`
- `www.example.com/brand/cat/item/product-item`
- `www.example.com/cat/item/product-item`

to: `www.example.com/product/item`

**item** can have values like `iphone-6-black-3g` (having hyphen in them)

## htaccess-code

I have made a test project and the following is in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 ### i have tested for ^.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^\-]+)-(.+)/?$  $2/$3.php?cat=$2&item=$3 [L,R=301]
```

If I redirect to `test.php?cat=$2&item=$3` it is showing correct values in `$2` and `$3`.

### Problem

But if I redirect it to `$2/$3.php` weird things happen.

Since the new URL generated also satisfy the rule so I think a loop occurs that 
continue until no more match....

To break the loop I have added `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200`, but it looks like it is not working.

I am getting crazy... the only solution coming to my head is change the **item** format like `apple_iphone-t` etc... Having first underscore and then hyphen. in this way no loop

**Kindly suggest if we can solve it with hyphen pattern?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just prevent the loop by adding some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^\-]+)-(.+)/?$  $2/$3.php?cat=$2&item=$3 [L,R=301]
```

The reason why `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` isn't working is because you are using an external redirect. You're redirecting the browser so the browser sends a *whole new request*, so there's no internal redirecting for that condition to work.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin it works When the file or directory does not exist...
But there is possibility that some files do exist
then it behave same